# Android opening input method setting activity does not work

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions

I am trying to launch input method setting from the application after clicking a button but it does not work
I tried to add a permission but does not work too

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(in);

        }

        private void startActivityForResult(Intent intent) {
        }
    });
```

and this is the manifest :

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.setting.INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="Myapp"
        android:label="@string/app"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">


        <meta-data android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method"/>



        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>

</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You should call a different [startActiivtyForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#StartActivity).
Then, in Your Activity, You should override a different [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html#ReceiveResult) method. Hope the links help You.

**EDIT**

Yes, it does work. See a very quickly made sample:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int INPUT_METHOD_RESULT = 947;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent in = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(in, INPUT_METHOD_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)     {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Returning from input settings with code: " + requestCode);
    }
}
```